# Struct with boxed impl trait

Tags: rust

I cannot figure out why this will not compile. I just want to have a struct with an iterator where the iterator is created with a function that returns `impl Trait`. I changed my code to a minimal example for this post.

[Open in Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=70562f4db9f9fd9fa115b846334e39bb)

```rust
struct Foo {
    pub it: Option<Box<dyn Iterator<Item=i32>>>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let it = Some(Box::new(my_numbers()));
        Self { it: it }
    }
}

fn my_numbers() -> impl Iterator<Item=i32> {
    1..10
}
```

Compiler output:

```
   |
8  |         Self { it: it }
   |                    ^^ expected trait object `dyn std::iter::Iterator`, found opaque type
...
12 | fn my_numbers() -> impl Iterator<Item=i32> {
   |                    ----------------------- the found opaque type
   |
   = note: expected enum `std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = i32> + 'static)>>`
              found enum `std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<impl std::iter::Iterator>>`
```

**Edit:**

I found one workaround is using `#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]`, but this is not stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting the boxed value, i.e. `Box::new(my_numbers()) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item=_>>` solves this with stable Rust 1.41.0. It's possible that enabling `type_alias_impl_trait` helps with this missing type inference aspect.

Comment: Perfect! And `type_alias_impl_trait` is a neat solution.